# Calculate area between two curves (that are normal distributions)

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, numeric

I need to calculate the area between two curves.
I have lots of data, so I'd like to do it programmatically.

Basically, I always have 2 normal distributions, calculated from a mean value and standard deviation. I would then like to calculate how much they intersect.
Here is an [example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/percentage-of-overlapping-regions-of-two-normal-distributions) of what I mean, and also some code in R (that I don't know).

Is there already a function in `matplotlib` or `scipy` or some other module that does it for me? 
In case I have to implement it myself, I think that I should do:

- find the intersections (there will be max 2)
- see which function is lower before, [between], and after the intersection
- calculate the integral of the lower function and add them all together

Is that right? How can I do the single steps? Are there functions, modules, etc that can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know R either, but the answer seems to be in the link you provided: just integrate the minimum of your distributions. 
You don't need to find intersections, just feed `min(f(x), g(x))` to `scipy.integrate.quad`.

Comment: that makes total sense.
i guess i was just thinking way to complicated.

Comment: quad() usually takes 3 arguments. try np.trapz(Y), e.g. where Y=min(f, g) is a single array of floats and f and g are ordered and of the same length.