# Find the common area between two graphs with multiple intersection points

Tags: r, plot, area, integral, kernel-density

I have following simulated data of following 2 variables. I created the density plot as follows,

```
set.seed(1)
x1=density(rnorm(100,0.5,3))
x2=density(rnorm(100,1,3))

plot(x1)
lines(x2)
```

[image]

Is there any function that can use to find the common area for  these 2 graphs using R ?

Do i need to perform an integration for intersecting points ?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [calculate area of overlapping density plot by ggplot using R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41914257/calculate-area-of-overlapping-density-plot-by-ggplot-using-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set the sequence both densities use for x values to be identical, you can use `pmin` on the y values. (Call `str(x1)` to see how they're stored.) For instance, to see how it works:

```r
set.seed(1)
x1 <- density(rnorm(100,0.5,3), from = -10, to = 10, n = 501)
x2 <- density(rnorm(100,1,3), from = -10, to = 10, n = 501)

plot(x2, main = 'Density intersection')
lines(x1)
polygon(x1$x, pmin(x1$y, x2$y), 20, col = 'dodgerblue')
```

[image: density intersection]

Taking the integral means just multiplying each `pmin` times the increment in the x sequence and summing the lot:

```r
sum(pmin(x1$y, x2$y) * diff(x1$x[1:2]))
#> [1] 0.896468
```